# Download with js a passbook generated from php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, passbook

i need to download a passbook file created with a php script in js ( angular application ) im trying to use this lib http://danml.com/download.html

im using this code in server side:

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="card.pkpass"');

echo base64_encode($this->pass_outputfile);
```

an this in client side:

```
var filename = responseInfo.headers["content-disposition"].indexOf("filename=");
filename = responseInfo.headers["content-disposition"].substring(filename+9);

var mime = responseInfo.headers["content-type"];

download(window.atob(response), filename.replace(/\"/g,''), mime);
```

the download starts well but the pkpass file is invalid... seems that the file is compressed 2 times... someone can tell me why??

Answer (score -1):

Ok i finally got it by decoding the base64 as a blob with this function,

```
function base64toBlob(base64Data, contentType) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    var sliceSize = 1024;
    var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
    var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
    var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
    var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

    for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
        var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
        var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

        var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
        for (var offset = begin, i = 0 ; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
            bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
        }
        byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
    }
    return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
}
```

and then just use the download function

```
download(base64toBlob(response,"application/vnd.apple.pkpass"), filename.replace(/\"/g,''), mime);
```

Comment: Wow, talk about using a sledgehammer to crack a nut!  `readfile($this->pass_outputfile);` instead of echoing a base64 stream should have been all you needed.

Comment: Ok but  i need to download it from js as an http response without saving the file before download it.... pass_outputfile isn't a file path

Comment: You could temporarily write it to disk and read it back, but if the above is working for you and you don't need to scale to hundreds of passes per second, you should be fine with doing this in memory.